# How to make SnackBar push up several FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

I have two FloatingActionButton in my layout. Both are attached the same way to the CoordinatorLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

[ appbar, toolbar, content... ]

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/anon_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onFabClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload_white_24dp"
            android:tint="?colorAccent"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/tint_inverted_fab"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinatorLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onFabClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_white_24dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinatorLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However, when I show a snackbar, only the FAB at the bottom moves up and down.

```
Snackbar.make(mCoordinator, "FAB pressed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

How to make both move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found is to implement the FloatingActionButton behaviour again and explicitly set it in your FABs.

On how to implement the default behaviour, the guys of BaseLab have a good article [here](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/) with its matching [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ggajews/coordinatorlayoutwithfabdemo/).

Once you create your own reimplementation of such behaviour, just set it in your layout file like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    [...]        
    app:layout_behavior="your.package.name.FloatingActionButtonBehavior"/>
```

Now *both* buttons will move when your SnackBar shows up!